# Linking Custom Content Types Together

Tags: views, files, nodes

I'm attempting to create a site that lists my brother's DVD releases.

I've been able to do this with Views, but I would like a more user friendly interface so I don't have to administer the site in the future, and my brother can do it himself.

Basically I have two Content Types:  Releases, and Scenes.

When creating a Release, I want (my brother) to be able to select Scenes that have already been added, and *arrange them in a specific order* as though they are a Custom Field in the Releases Content Type.

I don't think Views out of the box is friendly enough for my brother.

*Any* ideas, modules, hints, or search keywords that might help me engineer a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference module is what you're looking for. [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) is the standard right now, though there are other options such as [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).

To use your reference module, add a "node reference" field to your Release content type. When configuring that field, allow it to refer only to nodes of the "Scene" content type.

For the sort order, I believe if you use the autocomplete widget for your nodereference field then it should give you sorting capabilities on the Release node-add form, without needing another field in the Scene content type or any more work in Views. Just make sure when configuring the nodereference field that you set the number of allowed node references to "unlimited".

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on trying this out right now.  Is there an alternative way to handle arranging the order of them though? Because there are some Scenes that will be used in more than one Release, and with different Scene orders.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a better solution for sorting.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Solved! Thanks Jay.

Comment: Happy I could help.